# Problems with a htaccess and a folder inside with a tool

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website domain with a wordpress installed in the root, let's calle it:
mywebsite.com.

I also have a folder with an app that works indepent from the wordpress, i.e.:
mywebsite.com/tool

I need to update the htaccess file in order to change any link inside the folder from having WWW to not have and preserving directory and parameters

The problem is when I go to a route inside my app directory, for example this one
"https://www.mywebsite.com/tool/dfy/index.php?campaign=33&token=1" jumps to "https://mywebsite.com/dfy/?campaign=33&token=1" and gives an error

It's actually updating the www with a non www, but somehow it's forgetting "tool" and index.php... and it's pretty weird.

The htaccess in the root is like this:

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(/tool)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

---

The second part is related to keep the folders and inside routes, but as I mentioned before, it's not working.

I even add new htaccess files inside /tool and even on /tool/dfy with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But now I'm not sure which htaccess if dominating the others...

Any advice, help would be appreciated, thanks!

Final goal:
Convert this link:
"https://www.mywebsite.com/tool/dfy/index.php?campaign=33&token=1"
Into this:
"https://mywebsite.com/tool/dfy/index.php?campaign=33&token=1"
Having an htaccess WP file in the root.

UPDATED as suggested in the comments:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Exclude the "tool" folder from the previous rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^tool/(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/tool/dfy/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(/tool)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Still not working...

Comment: You should do the www-to-non-www redirect _first_, before the WP stuff.

Comment: First turn the engine off - `RewriteEngine Off`, then enable it again with the new rules

Comment: Hard to read in comments. Please edit your question and include the current state of the code in there, properly formatted.

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: 301 redirects are getting cached quite aggressively by browsers, so you might simply be seeing an outdated result at this point. Test in a private browser window to verify the issue still exists.

Comment: Tested in private browser, Makes this:
https://www.mywebsite.com/tool/dfy/index.php?campaign=99&token=1
Jump to this:
https://mywebsite.com/tool/dfy/dfy/?campaign=99&token=1
So it's adding a dfy folder and deleting index.php... Pretty weird...

Comment: Is the (second) `.htaccess` file you've posted in your question the one from the root? What `.htaccess` do you have in the `/tool` subdirectory? You should not be editing the WordPress-code-block in the `.htaccess` file in the root as WordPress itself will overwrite that (there is no need to edit that code block anyway). _Aside_ It's needs to be a **new** private browser session. You should be _testing_ with 302 (temp) redirect to avoid caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

Done!
Final htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Exclude the "tool" folder from the previous rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^tool/(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/tool/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: But this now _only_ targets the `/tool` subdirectory? (The removal of `index.php` in your updated code, as reported in your recent comment, would not be changed by this so that was presumably “something else”?)